# Write Cron Job in Java on GAE to Run BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I want to run a cron job on GAE that internally calls BigQuery.

I am currently able to run BigQuery but I need to log in with my credentials. But I would like to run the cron job for BigQuery without any login.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use the oauth2.0 token.

Comment: How i can use oauth2.0.As cron job is run by GAE and not by any user.Please provide some code in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am successfully able  to implement it in java.Before performing it we need to generate client id for service account.

```
private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
private static Bigquery bigquery;




AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential(Collections.singleton(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY));
bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName("BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not the java you're expecting. The secret is to use AppAssertionCredentials.
Here is the python sample:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
import httplib2
from google.appengine.api import memcache

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'

credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=scope)

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))

return build("bigquery", "v2", http=http)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to give java code for this.I tried out most of the things but still not able to done it.

Comment: here is the java doc for the relevant task: http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.6.0-beta/com/google/api/client/extensions/auth/helpers/appengine/AppAssertionCredential.html