# Authentication of Cron Job to Access Big Query

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I'm trying to setup a cron job in Google App Engine that has read/write access to Big Query data in an other project under the same domain. The cron job runs a Python module that has no user interaction or any other input from a web browser, so the authentication for Big Query access cannot be based on user's login info. What is the best way to achieve authentication in such a case?
I have tried the solution form here: [Write Cron Job in Java on GAE to Run BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895104/write-cron-job-in-java-on-gae-which-run-bigquery-from-this-cron-job/22896342#22896342)

but it gives me 401 errors when I hit Big Query API.

Comment: Have you tried this https://developers.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-appengine ?

Comment: I have tried this and I get: "...client.py:493] Refreshing due to a 401"

Comment: Can you post your code? The linked answer works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The linked code works without problem for me.

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=scope)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

print build("bigquery", "v2", http=http).datasets().list(projectId='gdelt-bq').execute(http)
```

Make sure that the BigQuery is activated on your project console:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/YOUR_PROJECT/apiui/api